# Python: Modifying Pandas DF rows that meets criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DF containing a BOM with prices:

| Assembly Level | Part Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FOOBARBAZQUX (Main assembly) | 100 |
| 2 | FOO (part) | 20 |
| 2 | BAR (part) | 30 |
| 2 | BAZ (subassembly) | 25 |
| 3 | BAZ_1 (child part of BAZ subassembly) | 15 |
| 3 | BAZ_2 (child subassembly of BAZ subassembly) | 10 |
| 4 | BAZ_2_1 (child part of BAZ_2 subassembly) | 10 |
| 2 | BOB (part) | 14 |
| 2 | QUX (subassembly) | 0 |
| 3 | QUX_1 (child part of QUX subassembly) | 12 |

If there are any subassemblies that contains a price thats not 0, then i'd like to replace all its child prices to its parent subassembly price. Like this:

| Assembly Level | Part Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FOOBARBAZQUX (Main assembly) | 100 |
| 2 | FOO (part) | 20 |
| 2 | BAR (part) | 30 |
| 2 | BAZ (subassembly) | 25 |
| 3 | BAZ_1 (child part of BAZ subassembly) | **25** |
| 3 | BAZ_2 (child subassembly of BAZ subassembly) | **25** |
| 4 | BAZ_2_1 (child part of BAZ_2 subassembly) | **25** |
| 2 | BOB (part) | 14 |
| 2 | QUX (subassembly) | 0 |
| 3 | QUX_1 (child part of QUX subassembly) | 12 |

Is there a good python way to do this?

Edit: Apologies for anything unclear. a subassembly can be differentiated by looking at the "Assembly level". If the "Assembly level" of the nth row is a lower number than its subsequent rows, then this indicates that the nth row is a "subassembly", and that the subsequent rows are the nth row's child. For example, BAZ is a subassembly (level 2) that contains children named BAZ_1 and BAZ_2 (level 3). BAZ_2 has its own child named BAZ_2_1 (level 4), so its also considered a subassy. BOB would not be part of the BAZ subassembly, as it is the same "Assembly Level" as BAZ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What defines a "subassembly"?

Comment: Subassembly is a part that is made of smaller parts (i.e. child parts)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear in that I was asking about the data in the question. What defines a "subassembly" in terms of the values in `Part Name`? Are you supposed to look for the word `subassembly` in the name?. In other words, how do you tell whether a given `Part Name` is a `part`, a `subassembly` or a `child`? And what about `BOB`? How do you know what that is since it's not mentioned anywhere else?

Comment: a subassembly can be differentiated by looking at the "Assembly level".  If the "Assembly level" of the nth row is a lower number than its subsequent rows, then this indicates that the nth row is a "subassembly", and that the subsequent rows are the nth row's child.

For example, BAZ is a subassembly (level 2) that contains children named BAZ_1 and BAZ_2 (level 3). BAZ_2 has its own child named BAZ_2_1 (level 4), so its also considered a subassy. BOB would not be part of the BAZ subassembly, as it is the same "Assembly Level" as BAZ.

I hope this makes sense haha...

Comment: So does that mean if `FOO` was a subassembly that the next row in the df would have `Assembly level = 3`, and then it would revert to `Assembly level = 2` again for `BAR`?

Comment: Also, if `BAZ_2` had `Price = 0`, what would be the expected result for `Price` for `BAZ_2_1`?

Comment: That’s correct, if ‘FOO’ is a subassembly, then its next row should be in ‘Assembly Level = 3’. However In the posted example, ‘FOO’ is not a subassembly, since ‘Assembly Level’ of ‘FOO’ == ‘Assembly Level’ of ‘BAR’.

Comment: If ‘BAZ_2’ had ‘Price = 0’ then ‘BAZ_2_1’ would stay the same. However this would be overwritten, since ‘BAZ != 0’. Thus all of its children and grandchildren ‘Price’ would be equal to ‘BAZ’ price

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach:

```
# extract leading codes from each Part Name
df["code"] = df["Part Name"].str.extract(r"([A-Z]+)")

# get subassembly codes whose Price == 0
subassemblies_zero_codes = df[
    (df["Part Name"].str.contains("subassembly")) & (df["Price"] == 0)
]["code"]

# get parent subassembly Price for each code, excluding zero
df_grouped = (
    df[["code", "Price"]]
    .loc[~df["code"].isin(subassemblies_zero_codes)]
    .groupby("code")
    .first()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"Price": "subassembly_price"})
)

# add parent subassembly prices to main df
df = pd.merge(df, df_grouped, how="left")

# replace Price with parent subassembly price where appropriate
df["Price"] = np.where(
    df["subassembly_price"].notna(), df["subassembly_price"], df["Price"]
)

# drop unused columns
df = df.drop(columns=["code", "subassembly_price"])
```

```
   Assembly Level                                     Part Name  Price
0               1                  FOOBARBAZQUX (Main assembly)  100.0
1               2                                    FOO (part)   20.0
2               2                                    BAR (part)   30.0
3               2                             BAZ (subassembly)   25.0
4               3         BAZ_1 (child part of BAZ subassembly)   25.0
5               3  BAZ_2 (child subassembly of BAZ subassembly)   25.0
6               4     BAZ_2_1 (child part of BAZ_2 subassembly)   25.0
7               2                                    BOB (part)   14.0
8               2                             QUX (subassembly)    0.0
9               3         QUX_1 (child part of QUX subassembly)   12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to compute a graph, then find the root per connected subgraph:

```
import networkx as nx

# extract node IDs
parent = df['Part Name'].str.extract(r'^(\w+)', expand=False)
child = df['Part Name'].str.extract(r'child \w+ of (\w+)', expand=False)
# create mapper of prices
prices = df.set_index(parent)['Price']
m = child.notna()

# create graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(zip(child[m], parent[m]), create_using=nx.DiGraph)
roots = {n for n, d in G.in_degree() if d==0}
# {'BAZ', 'QUX'}

# find root per subgraph
# and map the prices
d = {}
for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    r = next(iter(c & roots), None)
    for n in c:
        d[n] = prices.get(r)
# {'BAZ': 'BAZ', 'BAZ_1': 'BAZ', 'BAZ_2': 'BAZ', 'BAZ_2_1': 'BAZ', 'QUX_1': 'QUX', 'QUX': 'QUX'}

# replace price by that of the root of the subgraph
# except if it is 0
df['Price'] = child.map(d).replace(0, None).fillna(df['Price'])
```

Output:

```
   Assembly Level                                     Part Name  Price
0               1                  FOOBARBAZQUX (Main assembly)  100.0
1               2                                    FOO (part)   20.0
2               2                                    BAR (part)   30.0
3               2                             BAZ (subassembly)   25.0
4               3         BAZ_1 (child part of BAZ subassembly)   25.0
5               3  BAZ_2 (child subassembly of BAZ subassembly)   25.0
6               4     BAZ_2_1 (child part of BAZ_2 subassembly)   25.0
7               2                                    BOB (part)   14.0
8               2                             QUX (subassembly)    0.0
9               3         QUX_1 (child part of QUX subassembly)   12.0
```

Graph:

[image]